# Build native android library with maven

Tags: android, maven, android-ndk

I have builded android native library with runing ndk-build manualy successfully. At finish i have libraries for all definded platform in /libs/ directory.

Then I try to build same with maven plugin. In pom.xml I define next plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${android-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
         <ndk>
            <path>${env.ANDROID_NDK_HOME}</path>
         </ndk>
         <clearNativeArtifacts>false</clearNativeArtifacts>
         <ndkArchitectures>armeabi armeabi-v7a x86</ndkArchitectures>
         <sdk>
             <platform>${android.api.version}</platform>
             <path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</path>
         </sdk>                  
         <ndkBuildAdditionalCommandline>NDK_APP_OUT=${project.basedir}/obj/${android.liboutdir
         </ndkBuildAdditionalCommandline>
         <unndeployBeforeDeploy>false</undeployBeforeDeploy>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Run: `mvn compile`. Libs have been builded, have been located to /libs// and unfortunately have been deleted then. Here is log:

```
[WARNING] Excluding native dependency attached by this build
[INFO] executing 24 parallel jobs
[INFO] /home/user/android/android-ndk-r9/ndk-build [-C,     /home/user/workspace/webrtc/trunk/android/voice-client-native,     NDK_APPLICATION_MK=jni/default_debug.mk, -j, 24, NDK_TOOLCHAIN=arm-linux-androideabi-4.6,     APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a, NDK_APP_OUT=/home/user/workspace/webrtc/trunk/android/voice-    client-native/obj/default_debug, all]
[INFO] Building jar: /home/user/workspace/webrtc/trunk/android/voice-client native/target/voice-native-1.0-SNAPSHOT.har
[INFO] Cleaning up extracted include directories used for build
[INFO] Creating native output directory /home/user/workspace/webrtc/trunk/android/voice-client-native/libs/x86
```

Directory `libs` is empty, but libraries is located at `target/ndk-libs/` and it is'n right for me.

When I run `mvn install` I have next output:

```
Failed to install artifact com.tuenti.voice:voice-native:so:armeabi-v7a:1.0-SNAPSHOT: /home/user/workspace/webrtc/trunk/android/voice-client-native/libs/armeabi-v7a/libvoiceclient.so (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change following line in pom.xml

NDK_APP_OUT=${project.basedir}/obj/${android.liboutdir}

to

NDK_OUT=${project.basedir}/obj/${android.liboutdir} APP_ABI=all NDK_TOOLCHAIN=""

also please comment out nativeLibrariesDependenciesHardwareArchitectureOverrides tag.